# How to create a bulk software isntaller (ninite)

Tags: installation, windows-installer, exe, silent-installer

I want to be able to create different bulk installers to install specific programs on a computer. For example:

```
Technician Image:
- Adobe Reader 11
- AutoCAD
- Microsoft Lync
- Norton

Manager Image:
- ACT
- Adobe Reader 11
- Microsoft Lync
- Norton
```

These lists have more programs listed but this is an example. I would like to load windows on a machine and have an installer to do this for me. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Beginning with Windows Installer 4.5, you can install multiple Windows Installer packages using transaction processing by using [Multiple-Package Installations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/c4a0f4d8-818d-4e60-908b-adaa2a54de95) and the [MsiEmbeddedChainer Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/ac1e9c7b-bb83-4e1e-9108-211374c7d878). Older versions of the Windows Installer are unable to roll back the installation of multiple packages as a single transaction.